# What is the minimum disk space occupied by a neo4j node property?

Tags: neo4j

This article seems to imply a 41byte minimum on the disk space occupied by each property of a node, regardless of the property type.  For boolean and short node properties, this seems quite high.  Am I misunderstanding the article, or is this a correct and intended consequence of the fixed-size records in neo4j?  How can we minimize the disk space occupied by properties with small data types such as booleans or shorts?

https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-data-on-disk/